# Shift-JIS encoding with file

Tags: .net, encoding

I am trying to read a file using Shift-JIS encoding, however, it seems becoming invalid once it is read.

Infact, it is amazon order report file, and I am using simple code to read it.

```
        Dim FilePath As String = "C:\634125482017228.txt"
        Dim contents As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis"))
```

But once the file is read, it shows a little bit weird character

```
蟆丞ｸり憶逾・09060000007
```

Notice the "." it should be a tab instead. the Japanese name and the numbers are two different fields here separated by tab. But somehow, it is being read as a single field. Causing my parser to fail/read invalid values.

Is there any recommendations for this? Just to let you know that most of the files and records/rows in the files are read properly, just couple of rows causes above issue.
  thank you

Comment: Are you sure the file really has a tab? :-) If you open it with Notepad++ and set manually the encoding to Shift-Jis, what do you see?

Comment: In the Notepad++, it does show the same as read by code, i.e 蟆丞ｸり憶逾・09060000007 (with dot between two). However, using the default encoding or UTF8, it does separate them. For example, if I open in Excel, it does show two different fields, not single. And YES, if I use the shift-JIS encoding in excel, it also combine these two fields. Does that means, the Amazon is NOT providing the file correctly?

Comment: They seems to use the `・` as a separator. So simpy `Replace("・", "\t")`

Comment: Are you sure the file is shift-jis encoded and not UTF8 encoded?

Comment: Yes, its Sift-JIS, not UTF8. Using any other encoding doesn't provide correct values for the file, but some weird characters.

Comment: So try using the `Replace()` and see if it works out.

Comment: Replace? Where should I use the replace? Remember, this is not a generic document, it may or may not have this issue. Every time there will be different contents.

Comment: Try checking two or three documents and see if all the Shift-Jis encoded ones have the same problem

Comment: Definitely, I checked and most of the documents doesn't have issue. Only two documents (out of like 100) found this issue.

Comment: `if (!contents.Contains("\t")) { contents = contents.Replace("・", "\t"); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137345/discussion-between-sameers-javed-and-xanatos).